# Run javascript function on website/webapp when home button clicked on Android/IOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I want to call a function to save my last access time to the server. I have a api to call for that. I can do that when I close the window in the legitimate way but on andriod chrome or IOS safari mobile. But I am not able to trigger it when the Home button is clicked.

My current code for calling the api is as follows.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   //API call to store my last access time and session id
   };
```

This function will be called on window close. But I want an event which will fire when I am on a tablet or a mobile and press the home key. This will take my webapp to the background but wont close it.

Comment: Can you show us what you've already tried?

Comment: I am using something like this 
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   // My call to api to store last access time.
}

Comment: You need to edit the question and put that code in there.  What's wrong with it?  What happens?  Do you get any error messages?  Does it do anything at all?  You need to give us as much info as you can or we cannot help you.

Comment: Archer. I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

actually when you click the home button the app is still in process... It works same as how we minimize a window on a desktop.. the system is still in process only the status goes in sleep mode...

Comment: Let me test and will reply soon

Comment: Oouch!! I will let you know if I come across anything similar of this kind